Get users from Jira comments section in eazyBi report
Is it possible to create simple calculated field (No Javascript) to get only user names who put comments w.r.t each Jira issue in eazyBi report.
here is my code for review;
var commenta = new Array();
var allcomments = issue.fields.comment;
if (allcomments && allcomments.comments ) {
  var comments = issue.fields.comment.comments;
  for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
      var comment = comments[i];
      if(comment.author)
      {
      commenta.push(comment.author.displayName + ",1");
        }
    }
  let unique = commenta.filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i)
  issue.fields.customfield_comments_byuser = unique.join(" \n ");
}

